# jQuery img swap - keep width and height

Tags: jquery, css, image

I am having trouble getting an image swap to work correctly. The problem is that the the title placed underneath disappears behind the swapped image because it has position: absolute. I can get around the problem by applying a fixed height to an extra div around the images - but as this has to work in a responsive layout, the height is changeable.

I'm sure there is a simple solution, but can't figure it out.

Have created [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RnUqp/) & pasted code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="image_off">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/E8117F" class="image_on">
<h2>Title</h2>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
//image fade on hover
$('.image_off').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(200);
    $('.image_on').fadeIn(200).css('display', 'block');
});
$('.image_on').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(200);
    $('.image_off').fadeIn(200);
});
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to `fadeOut` the `image_off` element, as the image_on is fading in on the top.

If you'd like to retain this behaviour, you can animate the opacity to near-transparent, and then the `image_on` fades in anyway on the top.

Comment: Thanks! This works best as it maintains proper fading between images.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `position:absolute;`.

And Add a `callback function` in **JQuery**, so that the `.fadeIn()` and the `.fadeOut()` are executed one after the other.

```
$('.image_off').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(200,function(){
           $('.image_on').fadeIn(200).css('display', 'block');
    });

});
$('.image_on').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(200,function(){
          $('.image_off').fadeIn(200);
    });

});
```

Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/GTK8T/

Answer (score 0):

In case it's of any use to anyone, final jQuery used:

```
//image fade on hover
$('.image_off').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 200);
        $('.image_on').fadeIn(200).css('display','block');
});   
$('.image_on').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(200);
        $('.image_off').animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
});
```